# Finding Max value of multiple fields

Tags: sql, db2

I need help writing an sql query. I have a report which has values for columns that are different, but i need to have an extra column that gets the maximum value from the previous column and repeats it for every primary key.

I need sth like this:

`COL1-(PK) | COL2-(some int value) | COL3-max(COL2)
    1                 0                   3
    1                 3                   3
    1                 2                   3
    2                10                  15
    2                 7                  15
    2                15                  15`

Comment: SQL what? RDBMS please

Answer (score 2):

```
select col1, col2, (select max(col2) from tablename t2
                    where t1.col1 = t2.col1)
from tablename t1
```

A correlated sub-select is used to get each col1's max col2 value.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select col1, col2, max(col2) over (partition by col1) as col3
from table t;
```

This is what these functions are designed for.

By the way, your code seems to suggest that `col1` is a primary key.  Primary keys are not duplicated, so this is not a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY

```
SELECT COL1, MAX(COL2) AS MAX
FROM table
GROUP BY COL1
```